# Cors blocking me from GET-ing my server endpoint and redirecting

Tags: redirect, cors, nestjs

I'm trying to build an Oauth2 flow. Cors keeps blocking my GET request to my own server.

`localhost:3000` is the browser.
`localhost:3001` is the server.

I have cors setup in NestJS below and it works for every other non-redirecting endpoint:

```js
// main.ts
import { corsConfig } from '#common/config/index';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.enableCors({
    origin: [
      /^https?:\/\/localhost:3000/,
    ],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    credentials: true,
  });

  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001);
}
bootstrap();
```

When requesting to my server endpoint... these are the request.headers

```
{
  "host": "localhost:3001",
  "connection": "keep-alive",
  "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"100\"",
  "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) SomeStuff",
  "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Windows\"",
  "origin": "http://localhost:3000",
  "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
  "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
  "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
  "referer": "http://localhost:3000/",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
  "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,es;q=0.7,de;q=0.6",
  "cookie": "Authentication=someStuff"
}
```

When responding from my server, these are the response.headers

```
{
  "cross-origin-opener-policy": "same-origin",
  "cross-origin-resource-policy": "same-origin",
  "x-dns-prefetch-control": "off",
  "expect-ct": "max-age=0",
  "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
  "strict-transport-security": "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains",
  "x-download-options": "noopen",
  "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
  "origin-agent-cluster": "?1",
  "x-permitted-cross-domain-policies": "none",
  "referrer-policy": "no-referrer",
  "x-xss-protection": "0",
  "access-control-allow-origin": "http://localhost:3000",
  "vary": "Origin",
  "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
  "x-ratelimit-limit": "30",
  "x-ratelimit-remaining": "28",
  "x-ratelimit-reset": "60"
}
```

And this is the Cors error in my browser console

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/' (redirected from 
'http://localhost:3001/test') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource.
```

What do I need to change to allow a GET request to be redirected in the browser? Or is this not possible and it requires simply visiting the site with `window.location`?

Comment: What are you using to make the request?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Axios. I have withCredentials as true.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is not the ideal solution, but for my personal projects in a local environment, I used the "Moesif Origin & CORS Changer" browser extension to combat this annoying issue.

Google Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc

Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/moesif-origin-cors-changer1/